# How could I run a residential water line across a creek?

Tags: water, utilities

I'm looking at a new location for a house, and all utilities will need to cross a creek at some point - it's about 10 feet wide, 3 feet deep at the lowest spot. Due to the proximity of it to the road, I do not think boring under the creek would be very easy, and you can't run over it unless you use heat tape - but there is no electric near the creek.

My current thought is to just dig a trench across the ditch about 1 foot deeper than the bottom of the ditch (so 4 feet down), and then run the water line across there with concrete around the line, then filling it back in with dirt. Since this is well below the frost line, and the creek never completely freezes, it should be fine in the freeze/thaw cycles. I do realize, however, that I would need to get the appropriate permits before digging a trench through the ditch.

Does anyone have any additional suggestions or advice for this process?

Comment: You'll surely find local code addresses this. Depending on how dry it gets, you might be able to wait til the dry season and move the creek around in its bed as you work.   Consider putting electrical down there too in conduit, THWN-2 wire will totally handle that. (all outdoor conduit is presumed to be 100% flooded).

Comment: You'd be surprised what can be bored under and how close to a road.   We had a water lined bored under the street and it ended in a 3x5 trench between the sidewalk and street.  I'd investigate boring.

Comment: The best place to start is your municipal authority. Depending on local legislation, you may need special permission to dig in the creek. We have a creek with a know "endangered" species of fish in it, so all creek work have do be done with federal approval, and at the opposite end of the calendar year from their spawing cycle.

Comment: Where are you on this planet? This creek could be considered "navigable waters" in your jurisdiction, which would significantly influence who you need to talk to excavate within the banks.

Comment: I have 10 acres that has a creek that the summer flow is less than 2" but it connects to a fair sized river ~6 miles away so they classify this as a class 1 fish stream. 35k+ for permits to put a bridge over it without touching the banks setback for the supports was planned 10' so we now just use the property as a summer camping location and drive across the creek. The government can really stop you from touching the creek and the fines are huge for just doing the work. You really might investigate boring under the creek as Tyson suggests.

Comment: @Tyson I contacted a few boring companies and they said it was too far to travel, but they could if I _really_ needed it - basically a drastic increase in price. As for "navigable waters", this is just a wide part of a creek that passes through a culvert about 20 feet away - so I doubt it's navigable. But I'm in the eastern United States